# Accessing Guice singleton in a constructor

Tags: guice

I'm using Guice (Roboguice v2 to be exact with Guice v3) and I'm a bit new to it.

I have a singleton..

```
@Singleton
Accounts
{
    public Account[] getAllAccounts()
    {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

And I also have a class which needs access to the above in its constructor..

```
public class AccountListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Account>
{
    public AccountListAdapter(Context c)
    {
        super(c, R.layout.account_list_row, R.id.accountName, accounts.getAllAccounts());
    }

    ...
}
```

How can I gain access to the Accounts singleton above used as the last parameter of the super() call? As the constructor will execute before any instance variables are created.

Thanks!

Comment: are you creating the AcountListAdapter during an Activity onCreate()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle this two ways.

First you could inject the Adapter directly into your Activity.  This will include the current Context as well as the singelton:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends RoboActivity{

     @Inject
     private AccountListAdapter accountListAdapter;

     ....
     //then register it with your listView in your onCreate()
 }
```

keep in mind you need to add the following annotation:

```
public class AccountListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Account>
{
    @Inject
    public AccountListAdapter(Context c, Accounts acconts)
    {
        super(c, R.layout.account_list_row, R.id.accountName, accounts.getAllAccounts());
    }

    ...
}
```

Second, you could construct the object yourself during the onCreate():

```
public class ExampleActivity extends RoboActivity{

     @Inject
     private Account accounts;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

         AccountListAdapter accountListAdapter = new AccountListAdapter(this, accounts);

     //then register it with your listView
 }
```

You may have to extend the Roboguice ListActivity instead of the RoboActivity to use the ListActivity successfully.  Let me know if this works for you.